# How can I compare two values in a grouped data which are in different columns and rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset `[10000x61]` in which I want to compare two columns. Let's call them column 3 and column 4. The rows are already grouped in different group_ids. Here is a example of one group, which I grouped with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    data = pd.DataFrame([['Value1', 'Value2','2010-12-06' , '2014-03-14'],
 ['Value1', 'Value2','2014-04-13', '2017-10-01'], 
['Value1', 'Value2','2017-11-01',''],
['Value3', 'Value4', '2010-12-06', '2011-03-14'], 
['Value3', 'Value4', '2014-04-13', '2017-10-01']], columns=['ColumnA', 'ColumnB', 'ColumnC', 'ColumnD'])

    grouping_data = data[["ColumnA", "ColumnB"]]
    group_ids = (
        (grouping_data != grouping_data.shift()).any(axis="columns").cumsum()
    )
    result = data.loc[
        group_ids.groupby(group_ids)
        .filter(lambda group: len(group) >= 2)
        .index
    ]
   
    result.to_excel('result.xlsx', index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code grouped them by Column A and Column B.

Here is an example table. Note: This is only **one** of many groups.

```
| Column A | Column B || Column C | Column D   |
| -------- | -------- || -------- | --------   |
| Value1   | Value2   ||2010-12-06| 2014-03-14 |
| Value1   | Value2   ||2014-04-13| 2017-10-01 |
| Value1   | Value2   ||2017-11-01|            |
| Value3   | Value4   ||2010-12-06| 2011-03-14 |
| Value3   | Value4   ||2014-04-13| 2017-10-01 |
```

What I want:

```
| Column A | Column B || Column C | Column D   |
| -------- | -------- || -------- | --------   |
| Value1   | Value2   ||2010-12-06| 2014-03-14 |
| Value1   | Value2   ||2014-04-13| 2017-10-01 |
| Value1   | Value2   ||2017-11-01|
```

What I want to do within every group:

`1.   ((2014-04-13)-(2014-03-14))<70`
`2.   ((2014-03-14)-(2010-12-06))>900`

Both need to  be true. If not, I want the whole group to be deleted (or to put it simply:delete the rows). There are groups with max. 3 rows, so in this example `((2017-11-01)-(2017-10-01))<70` and`((2017-10-01)-(2014-04-13))>900` needs to be checked aswell.

Important notice: The content in the Column C and D are dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. In Column D are sometimes blank which made it difficult for me because in pandas you can't use the date `0000-00-00.` But I want to be zero otherwise there will be wrong calculations.

I tried using `.shift()` an `np.where` but I can't find a working solution. Especially integrating the new filter into the old one while using the already grouped rows is giving me a hard time.
This is what my code looks like right now:

```
import pandas as pd

def main1():
    data = pd.DataFrame([['Value1', 'Value2','2010-12-06' , '2014-03-14'],
 ['Value1', 'Value2','2014-04-13', '2017-10-01'], 
['Value1', 'Value2','2017-11-01',''],
['Value3', 'Value4', '2010-12-06', '2011-03-14'], 
['Value3', 'Value4', '2014-04-13', '2017-10-01']], columns=['ColumnA', 'ColumnB', 'ColumnC', 'ColumnD'])
    
   #filler for 0000-00-00, haven't found a solution yet.
    fill_value = pd.to_datetime('2001-01-01', format='%Y-%m-%d')
    data['ColumnD'].fillna(fill_value, inplace=True)
    
    data['ColumnC'] = pd.to_datetime(data['ColumnC'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    data['ColumnD'] = pd.to_datetime(data['ColumnD'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    
    grouping_data = data[["ColumnA", "ColumnB"]]
    group_ids = (
        (grouping_data != 
      grouping_data.shift()).any(axis="columns").cumsum()
    )
        result = data.loc[
        group_ids.groupby(group_ids)
        .filter(lambda group: len(group) >= 2)
        .index
    ]
         
    # Zusätzliche Bedingungen
    condition1 = ((data['ColumnC'].shift() - data['ColumnD'])).dt.days < 70
    condition2 = ((data['ColumnD'] - data['ColumnC'])).dt.days > 900
    
    condition1 = condition1.fillna(False)
    condition2 = condition2.fillna(False)

    combined_condition = condition1 & condition2
           
    filtered_group_ids = group_ids[group_ids.map(lambda x: x if x in combined_condition.index else False)]
    #filtered_group_ids = group_ids[group_ids.map(combined_condition)]
        
    result = data.loc[data.groupby(group_ids).filter(lambda group: group.name in filtered_group_ids.index).index]
    
if __name__ == "__main1__":
    main1()
```

Comment: Hi pyflo, can you *show* us what your data is like, instead of telling us? You can use df.to_csv()

Comment: @Mark I edited my code, sorry!

Comment: uhhh the code isn't the point, it's the lack of ***data***

Comment: @Mark What data exactly? I thought my example data would be enough but I can provide extra data when u specify it.

Comment: read this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @Mark Can you edit my path pls? I forgot to remove it. Secondly, I did provide an example as stated in your link. I am not gonna provide the whole data I used for obvious reasons. If you could tell me what data exactly is missing to understand my problem I will happily provide it.

Comment: `Important notice: The content in the Column C and D are dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD.`  1. in your example, they aren't, which makes it a bad example, and 2. it's not a dataframe. We shouldn't have to do the work of recreating your dataframe ourselves (badly)

Comment: So no, you didn't provide an example, like in the link. Tag me when you *actually* provide a working example (e.g. the first 6 lines of your dataframe, verbatim)

Comment: @Mark Should be good now. I will remember it for my next post, thanks!

Comment: Where do the cell references come from and what are they referring to?

Comment: @JesseSealand I corrected some of the cell references but it would be nice of you if you could tell me which cell references you refer to.

Comment: I may just be misunderstanding but in columns A and B of your example table, what are "Cell 1", "Cell 2"..

Comment: @JesseSealand You're right, that's misleading. With my first example of code I filtered out the group given in my example table. Only when Value1 in ColumnA is the same as the previous row & if Value2 in ColumnB is the same as the previous row it keeps the group. That's how my groups are build. I added a table. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @JesseSealand any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

**Getting Started**:

Here is one approach that might help you break through this. I can group the data together for you in a different way that might be easier for you to apply the selection logic. See if this helps.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Value1', 'Value2','2010-12-06' , '2014-03-14'],
['Value1', 'Value2','2014-04-13', '2017-10-01'], 
['Value1', 'Value2','2017-11-01',''],
['Value3', 'Value4', '2010-12-06', '2011-03-14'], 
['Value3', 'Value4', '2014-04-13', '2017-10-01']], columns=['ColumnA', 'ColumnB', 'ColumnC', 'ColumnD'])
    
#filler for 0000-00-00
df.replace({'': '2001-01-01'}, inplace=True)
```

Then we assemble the dates for each group as an ordered list into a new column.

```
df['value_pair'] = df[['ColumnC','ColumnD']].values.tolist()

df_grouped = df.groupby(['ColumnA','ColumnB'])['value_pair'].apply(list).reset_index()
df_grouped['value_pair'] = df_grouped[['value_pair']].applymap(np.concatenate)
df_grouped['value_pair'] = df_grouped[['value_pair']].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
df_grouped


#   ColumnA ColumnB value_pair
#0  Value1  Value2  [2010-12-06, 2014-03-14, 2014-04-13, 2017-10-0...
#1  Value3  Value4  [2010-12-06, 2011-03-14, 2014-04-13, 2017-10-01]
```

From here will you be able to process the difference between dates and apply the logic to determine if they meet the appropriate criteria?

Comment: I'm stll not 100% sure about how the date logic works so I thought we could start here.

Comment: Thank you very much! I encountered one small problem when using my original data imported from excel. When using .values.tolist() it actually converts my dates wrong. The dates look like this now: 1291593600000000000. I think it has to do something with panda and numpy getting mixed as far as I read it right in the forum. I unfortunately can't find a solution for that. Do you have one in mind? @Jesse Sealand

Comment: Your time is in [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You will need to convert to a datetime object then make it the appropriate format. For each column, try df[colname] = pd.to_datetime(df[colname]) then convert to datetime object df[colname] = df[colname].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ). This should give you the expected strings.

Comment: that fixed it, thanks! But now my rows are in the wrong order. I had this situation earlier before aswell. I tried playing around with .reset:index() and .groupby but it just does not want to work out. @Jesse Sealand

Comment: Would sorting the rows by columns put them back into order?

Comment: That's a good idea but in my case it would not work cause the values in the original dataset are not in order like in my example, sorry.
To be precise: the last row (group) now is at the top. The rest is in the right order
Edit: With 
data_grouped = result.groupby(['Baum2','Baum7'])['value_pair'].apply(list).reset_index() and
data_grouped = pd.concat([data_grouped.iloc[-1:], data_grouped.iloc[:-1]], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
it worked now. But I have to write .reset_index() twice which doesn't seem that pretty. Any way I can avoid that? @Jesse Sealand

Comment: We're getting off topic, perhaps post another question about simplifying your two grouping statements into something more simple without resetting the index twice. I think that will be more productive.

Comment: You're right. Then back to the topic: When trying to do the initial thing (subtracting dates) it gives me the error 'unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.str_' and 'numpy.str_'' cause I am subtracting strings (my dates). I am doing the following: erg1 = data_grouped['value_pair'][0][2]-data_grouped['value_pair'][0][1]. If I am seeing this right we needed to make the dates strings to show the right thing but now this is what is causing the error? @Jesse Sealand